# "overflow: hidden" let the text go over <article>

Tags: html, css

When I try to use `overflow: hidden;`, the result isn't that I expect.
The article has the good size on big screens, but on small screens, the text is too big so it's over the article..

```css
.article {
  padding: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.50rem black;
}

.article_img {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article class="article">
    <img class="article_img" src="https://cdn.easycash.fr/img/prod/0/0/3/9/4/1/9/8/1/src/6556940-sony-ps3-slim-noir-320-go-sans-manette.jpg">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p style="overflow: hidden;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce lacinia laoreet leo eget congue. Vestibulum vulputate sed risus vel accumsan. Vivamus sed rhoncus libero. Sed placerat dolor id velit pharetra, vitae vehicula augue convallis. In nec euismod
      felis. Nunc eget ornare ligula. Praesent finibus ipsum at imperdiet imperdiet. Aenean at pulvinar ligula, nec rhoncus metus. Vivamus luctus lobortis enim, quis facilisis diam pulvinar ut. Integer ultricies pellentesque leo, sed bibendum justo sollicitudin
      vitae. Sed dictum ipsum et bibendum porta. Nam vulputate tempus dui vel volutpat. Donec massa diam, fringilla eu neque sed, mattis tincidunt tortor. Nulla neque purus, dictum non porttitor vitae, fermentum rhoncus lorem. Donec eleifend ultricies
      justo, pretium interdum magna tempus vel. Suspendisse ultrices, tortor at placerat commodo, ligula diam feugiat felis, eget consectetur nibh est et dolor.</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

Result:
[image]

Expected (approx.):
[image]

Comment: Get rid of the `max-height: 200px;`

Comment: The problem is that I want the height to be set to the maximum of 200px

Comment: Your `p` has `height: auto` (the default), so an overflow on `p` never occurs. Also there is no standard CSS property that allows multi-line text-overflow to be controlled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, you can use the proprietary `-webkit-line-clamp` and define the number of lines you want:

```css
html { box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *::before, *::after, *::marker { box-sizing: inherit; }

.line-clamp-5 {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.article {
  padding: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.50rem black;
}

.article_img {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article class="article">
    <img class="article_img" src="https://cdn.easycash.fr/img/prod/0/0/3/9/4/1/9/8/1/src/6556940-sony-ps3-slim-noir-320-go-sans-manette.jpg">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <p class="line-clamp-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce lacinia laoreet leo eget congue. Vestibulum vulputate sed risus vel accumsan. Vivamus sed rhoncus libero. Sed placerat dolor id velit pharetra, vitae vehicula augue convallis. In nec euismod
      felis. Nunc eget ornare ligula. Praesent finibus ipsum at imperdiet imperdiet. Aenean at pulvinar ligula, nec rhoncus metus. Vivamus luctus lobortis enim, quis facilisis diam pulvinar ut. Integer ultricies pellentesque leo, sed bibendum justo sollicitudin
      vitae. Sed dictum ipsum et bibendum porta. Nam vulputate tempus dui vel volutpat. Donec massa diam, fringilla eu neque sed, mattis tincidunt tortor. Nulla neque purus, dictum non porttitor vitae, fermentum rhoncus lorem. Donec eleifend ultricies
      justo, pretium interdum magna tempus vel. Suspendisse ultrices, tortor at placerat commodo, ligula diam feugiat felis, eget consectetur nibh est et dolor.</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

This property is in the process of being standardized as `line-clamp`, but not implemented yet.

Further information:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp
- https://caniuse.com/css-line-clamp

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `display: flex` to make columns to be aligned like `row`. Then if you want to avoid overflow, we can delete `max-height`:

```css
.article {
  padding: 35px;
  width: 100%;

  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.50rem black;
}

img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.one {
  flex-basis: 10%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.two {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <article class="article">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="one">
          <img class="article_img"
            src="https://cdn.easycash.fr/img/prod/0/0/3/9/4/1/9/8/1/src/6556940-sony-ps3-slim-noir-320-go-sans-manette.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="two">
          <h1>Test</h1>
          <p style="overflow: hidden;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce lacinia laoreet
            leo
            eget congue. Vestibulum vulputate sed risus vel accumsan. Vivamus sed rhoncus libero. Sed placerat dolor id
            velit pharetra, vitae vehicula augue convallis. In nec euismod felis. Nunc eget ornare ligula. Praesent
            finibus
            ipsum at imperdiet imperdiet. Aenean at pulvinar ligula, nec rhoncus metus. Vivamus luctus lobortis enim,
            quis
            facilisis diam pulvinar ut. Integer ultricies pellentesque leo, sed bibendum justo sollicitudin vitae. Sed
            dictum ipsum et bibendum porta. Nam vulputate tempus dui vel volutpat. Donec massa diam, fringilla eu neque
            sed,
            mattis tincidunt tortor. Nulla neque purus, dictum non porttitor vitae, fermentum rhoncus lorem. Donec
            eleifend
            ultricies justo, pretium interdum magna tempus vel. Suspendisse ultrices, tortor at placerat commodo, ligula
            diam feugiat felis, eget consectetur nibh est et dolor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
    </div>
  </section>
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to have a fixed height, then it is necessary to use `overflow-y: scroll`. Otherwise, the content of will overflow `article` element:

```css
.article {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 35px;
  max-height: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.50rem black;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.one {
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  white-space: nowrap;

}

.two {
  flex: 0 0 80%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: normal;
  height: 100%;
}


.article_img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding-right: 25px;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.ellipsis {
  display: -webkit-box;
  overflow : hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <article class="article">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="one">
          <img class="article_img"              src="https://cdn.easycash.fr/img/prod/0/0/3/9/4/1/9/8/1/src/6556940-sony-ps3-slim-noir-320-go-sans-manette.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="two">
          <h1>Test</h1>
          <div class="ellipsis">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce lacinia laoreet
            leo
            eget congue. Vestibulum vulputate sed risus vel accumsan. Vivamus sed rhoncus libero. Sed placerat dolor id
            velit pharetra, vitae vehicula augue convallis. In nec euismod felis. Nunc eget ornare ligula. Praesent
            finibus
            ipsum at imperdiet imperdiet. Aenean at pulvinar ligula, nec rhoncus metus. Vivamus luctus lobortis enim,
            quis
            facilisis diam pulvinar ut. Integer ultricies pellentesque leo, sed bibendum justo sollicitudin vitae. Sed
            dictum ipsum et bibendum porta. Nam vulputate tempus dui vel volutpat. Donec massa diam, fringilla eu neque
            sed,
            mattis tincidunt tortor. Nulla neque purus, dictum non porttitor vitae, fermentum rhoncus lorem. Donec
            eleifend
            ultricies justo, pretium interdum magna tempus vel. Suspendisse ultrices, tortor at placerat commodo, ligula
            diam feugiat felis, eget consectetur nibh est et dolor.
           </div>
        </div>        
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
```

Comment: That can be a solution, but I want the height to be at the maximum of 200px

Comment: Not excatly what I'm searching for... But I think I will try to use something else because I'm locked with this for a long time...

Comment: @Lunyx please, see my updated answer. It looks like that it is desirable requirements in your question. I know that you've marked an answer, so I am not asking to mark my reply as an answer. I just wanted to show whether it is ok for you. Feel free to upvote if it was helpful to you:).